# Encoding issues in Arcpy, appears unicode?

Tags: arcpy, encoding

I have a column that has Greek characters:

Example:

```
Like "*\u0395\u03a*")
```

What can I do to make it appear as it should?

What I have tried:

```
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')
```

It didn't work.

When I print it in the console it looks with unicode. If I check the attribute table looks normal.

To be more specific:

If I try this:

```
datasetList = arcpy.ListTables("*") # Here putting the name of the table
... 
... for dataset in datasetList:
...      with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(dataset, ["TheTableName","SqlString"]) as cur:
...           for row in cur:
...               print row
```

It gives:

```
(u'Wes1', u'SELECT Wes1.KA, \r\nFROM Wes1\r\nWHERE (Wes1.KA) Not Like "*\u0395\u039a*"'))
```

Example of table

```
  qname TheTableName SqlString
0   shp_q1  Wes1     SELECT ...
1   shp_q2  Wes2     SELECT ...
2   shp_q3  Wes3     SELECT ...
```

each Wes1,2,3 are files in a gdb.

The result with the unicode said above is produced in the terminal(python editor for ArcPy) INSIDE ArcMap.

Comment: The problem is Arcgis related that's why I posted here. I have tried :  `sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')` but didn't work.

Comment: For coding questions a code snippet that illustrates what you have tried and where you are stuck is expected.

Comment: it is part of an sql quote inside a column hence the 'like' expression and it looks exactly as the example.

Comment: The code snippet that you have presented contains no code using a spatial library.  You mention ArcPy in your title but that makes no appearance in the question body that it is intended to summarize. Python code unrelated to spatial libraries is best researched at [so].

Comment: Yes. This is about arcpy but I dont know how to solve it in Arcpy.

Comment: The code snippet that you have presented is not using ArcPy.

Comment: That's the point of the question. How to do it in Arcpy. Am I not saying it right?

Comment: This could be an interesting question, but I have a feeling it's not well understood (yet) :-) Could you please try to explain better what it is you want to achieve, and where you get stuck? For instance: I want *X*, but I get *Y*. It may also help to attach screenshots that illustrate your problem.

Comment: I have a suspicion that https://stackoverflow.com/a/44538293/820534 may be the key to this.  If the asker is storing unicodes in a field of a feature class then a cursor should be able to read them and plug them into a formatted string as per the link.

Comment: "What can I do to make it appear as it should?" - where precisely do you want it to appear?  In a text element of a layout?  As a layer label? Or somewhere else?

Comment: When I print it in the console it looks with unicode. If I check the attribute table looks normal.

Comment: Please include a picture of a few rows and columns from your attribute table in your question.  When you say "the console", do you mean the Python window of ArcMap, ore something else?

Comment: It can be a pain to work with UTF-16 strings in Python 2.7, but there's nothing ArcGIS-specific about this.

Comment: Well, if I was working with geopandas I would add `encoding = 'utf-8' when reading the file for example. Here working with Arcpy I don't know how to declare it. That's why I consider it an Arc related question.

Comment: No, file geodatabase and most of Desktop is already Unicode, so you just need to use standard Python to convert UTF-16 to UTF-8.